# Cambiar dato de array multidimensional con spread operator en reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objeto, jsonobject

tengo un Json que contiene entre sus propiedades una que es un `Array` con 2 propiedades `Answer` y `Value`. Necesito acceder y cambiar el contenido de la propiedad `Answer[]` estoy trabajando con React, El Json que se encuentra en un useState es el siguiente

```
const [cadenaOpcion, setCadenaOpcion] = useState(
  {
    "question": "Aca va la pregunta",
    "answer": [
        {
            "answer": "Respuesta Uno",
            "value": true
        },
        {
            "answer": "Respuesta dos",
            "value": false
        },
        {
            "answer": "Respuesta tres",
            "value": false
        }
    ]
  }
  )
;
```

Por un lado mapeo el mismo mostrando las propiedades de `answer[]` y dando la opción de editarlos enviándole a través de un (event) los datos.

```
  cadenaOpcion.answer.map((contenido, index) => 
            <ListItem button key={contenido}>
              <textarea name = "answer" id={index} rows ="2" placeholder='Respuesta' onChange={event => opcionOnChange(event)}></textarea> 
              <select name="value" id={index} onChange={event => opcionOnChange(event)}><option value="true" >True</option><option value="false" selected>False</option></select>                 
            </ListItem>    
  )
```

Y esto es lo que estoy haciendo para modificar el campo en cada indice de Answer[], envío por el id, cargando el dato obtenido por event.target.id

```
  const opcionOnChange = (event, key) => {

    let id = Number(event.target.id);

      setCadenaOpcion(

        oldArray =>({ ...oldArray,
        
        answer: [...oldArray.answer,

        [id]: {...oldArray.answer[id],

        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        
        } 
         ] }))
  }
```

Esto no estaría andando, ya que no me deja guardar en el mismo formato de json, por lo cual una vez cambiado me rompe el mapeo al volver a renderizarse.

Comment: Depronto puedes aclarar mejor la pregunta... puedes poner un ejemplo de a que te refieres con "cambiar uno a un nivel inferior"? puedes poner un ejemplo de que variables tienes y como esperas que quede el resultado dentro del estado? que es id? que es event.target.name? que es oldArray? (nos toca suponer muchas cosas)

Comment: Si por su puesto

Comment: Si por su puesto 

El event target es un evento de un campo de texto, con el le mando el contenido de el mismo y su id, para poder ubicarlo en que posición se guarda

```
              <textarea name = "answer" id={index} rows ="2" placeholder='Respuesta' onChange={event => opcionOnChange(event)}></textarea>
 
              <select name="value" id={index} onChange={event => opcionOnChange(event)}><option value="true" >True</option><option value="false" selected>False</option></select>        
               
  )
```

Comment: Mejor edita tu pregunta para incluir nuevos datos... el código en los comentarios no es para nada legible, mejor edita tu pregunta y agrega la mayor cantidad de detalles que puedas para ayudarte. Tambien puedes revisar [ask]. saludos.

Comment: Gracias Pipe es las primera vez que uso esta plataforma, ya edite a ver si quedo mas claro.